# How to fetch data and then redirect user with POST data in single action in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

When a user clicks a button in React how to

1. Make a POST request to server A
2. Redirect the user to a server B with POST data from the response from server A?

As far as I know the redirect with POST data can only be done by submitting a form element, but how to add several hidden fields from the response from server A before submitting the form?

This would be easy using two clicks but for better user experience I want to combine them. For context this is for [Paytrail Payment API](https://docs.paytrail.com/) where I want to create the payment and proceed to provider's site in a single click.

Comment: it's not possible to redirect with post automagically, you need to redirect with Url parameters after the success response: window.location.href = 'http://mynexturl.com?token=whatever_value&otherParameter=othervalue'

Comment: Execute the POST to server A programmatically using [the fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), extract what you need from the response and post it to server B?